# Why hasn't my reputation gone back up from 1 after a suspension?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, privileges, account-suspension

I recently got suspended (stupid me, I know) on Stack Overflow.

However, I have noticed that, after my suspension, my reputation has not gone back up to what it was before.
I saw a question on Meta that said that it is **temporarily** set to 1.

My reputation is still 1 now, and I have lost all my privileges.
Is this a bug in the site, or has the post-suspended account to start of again with 1 reputation?

Comment: I fixed that for you, via a rep recalc.  I apologize to the devs if that makes it harder to track down the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When coming out of suspension your reputation is automatically recalculated. We run these recalculations once per hour, you simply have to wait for that to happen.  In this case a moderator manually recalced you, but the same would have happened automatically 16 minutes later.

Comment: And this is why I've learned to wait a day or two before posting any "bug" reports. :P